Generate a PuTTY-compatible private key with a passphrase
I want to generate a private key that is encrypted with a passphrase and can be used by PuTTYgen. My solution only needs to work on .NET 8. While a PPK in proprietary PuTTY format would be nice, I'm fine with any format that can be imported/converted using the PuTTYgen conversion utility.
string passphrase = "foo";
using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create(4096))
{
    return rsa.ExportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKeyPem(
        passphrase,
        new PbeParameters(PbeEncryptionAlgorithm.Aes256Cbc, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, 100000));
}

The above code exports a PKCS#8 encrypted PEM with the passphrase, but the resulting output cannot be opened and converted by PuTTYgen.
Ideally using native .NET (but also willing to use Renci library), how can I generate the desired output?

I'm not sure about a native way with .net only - but would it be an option to run a command through the command line interface and let it generate by puttygen (so puttygen has to be installed on the system where your code is running)? Otherwise you might have to use some cyptographic library - I think a native .NET implementation would require quite much complexity.

@spcial No, sorry, that's not an option for me at this time.
